# how to add an external spring application as a portlet to a liferay portal

Tags: spring, primefaces, liferay, portlet

I have developed a Primefaces- Spring Application. 
I have installed Liferay IDE/Plugings/server. I Want to deploy the Primeface-Spring application a s a portlet to my Liferay Portal. How do i achieve it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... if I well undestood, you create a standard web application and need to deploy it as a portlet?

I'm sad to say that it is impossible: you need to convert your webapp to a "portlet application" before deploy.

By the way Liferay tries to meet your need... you can deploy your webapp inside your application server like any other web application. So your webserver will be able to serve Liferay (in root context) or your application in its context. Then you have to embed it inside a liferay "Embedded page": just create an "Embedded" page using your Liferay admin features.
This solution uses an iframe, so if you prefer you can try to use a "web-proxy" portlet (to integrate your code server side): see here http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Proxy+Portlet

Next time you develop a portlet application a good starting point is to understand basics on portlet lifecycle, then to develop it directly thinking on a portlet.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to deploy your PrimeFaces+Spring web application as a portlet in Liferay using [Liferay Faces Bridge](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/bridge). The purpose of the bridge is to provide developers with a way to develop JSF applications without being concerned about the Portlet API. The [Liferay Faces](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/overview) project has a [primefaces4-portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#primefaces4-portlet) demo and a [jsf2-spring-portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#jsf2-spring-portlet) demo that you can download in order to verify that these technologies work in your Liferay Portal environment.

Comment: Could you please give me the steps to do so?

Comment: I recommend that you read the sections titled [Liferay Faces](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/liferay-faces-jsf-portlets) and [Creating and Deploying JSF Porltets](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-and-deploying-jsf-portlets) in the official Liferay documentation.

Comment: Also I recommend that you read the [PrimeFaces Portlet Tutorial](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/PrimeFaces+Portlet+Tutorial) in the Liferay Faces Wiki.